# Get specific row from database with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

I'm new to this so i have this silly question.I want to make a login form and when the user logs in i want to show all his information in the screen(username attack defence...).The thing is i don't know how to call the specific function i've made because in my controller calls function index() by default and not the function guser().

login view

```html
<h2>Login</h2>
<?php if($error==1){ ?>
<p>Your Username/password did not match </p>
<?php } ?>

<form action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/Users/login" method="post">
<p>Username: <input name="user" type="text" /> </p>
<p>Password: <input name="password" type="password" /> </p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>
</form>
```

users controller

```
<?php

    class Users Extends CI_Controller{

        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('User');
        }

        function index(){
            $data['users']=$this->User->get_users();//sto model post tha kalesei tin sinartisi get_posts
            $this->load->view('Post_index',$data);
        }

        function guser($id){
            $data['user']=$this->User->get_user($id);
            $this->load->view('Post_index',$data);
        }

        function login(){
            $data['error'] = 0; // simenei oti den exei errors
            if($_POST){ 
                $user=$this->input->post('user',true);//pairnei to username p edose o xristis(einai idio me to $_POST)
                $password=$this->input->post('password',true);//pairnei to password p edose o xristis
                //$type=$this->input->post('charact',true);
                $user1=$this->User->login($user,$password);//,$type);
                if(!$user1){
                    $data['error']=1;

                }else{

                    $this->session->set_userdata('id',$user1['id']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('user',$user1['user']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('name',$user1['name']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('money',$user1['money']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('attack',$user1['attack']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('defence',$user1['defence']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('level',$user1['level']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('xp',$user1['xp']);
                    redirect(base_url().'index.php/Users');
                }

            }
            $this->load->view('Login',$data);
        }

        function registerSam(){
            if($_POST){
                $data=array(
                    'user'=>$_POST['user'],
                    'name'=>$_POST['name'],
                    'password'=>$_POST['password'],
                    'charact'=>"Samurai",
                    'money'=>400,
                    'attack'=>10,
                    'defence'=>5,
                    'level'=>0,
                    'xp'=>0
                    );
                $userid=$this->User->create_user($data);


            }

        }

        function registerKnight(){
            if($_POST){
                $data=array(
                    'user'=>$_POST['user'],
                    'name'=>$_POST['name'],
                    'password'=>$_POST['password'],
                    'charact'=>"Knight",
                    'money'=>400,
                    'attack'=>5,
                    'defence'=>10,
                    'level'=>0,
                    'xp'=>0
                    );
                $userid=$this->User->create_user($data);


            }

        }
    }
?>
```

user model

```
<?php 

    class User Extends CI_Model{

        function create_user($data){
            $this->db->insert('unityusers',$data);
        }

        function login($user,$password){
            $where=array(
                'user'=>$user,
                'password'=>$password,
                );
            $this->db->select()->from('unityusers')->where($where);
            $query=$this->db->get();
            return $query->first_row('array');
        }

        function get_user($id){
            $this->db->select()->from('unityusers')->where(array('id'=>$id));
            $query=$this->db->get();
            return $query->first_row('array');
        }
        function get_users($num=20,$start=0){// tha paroume 20 posts k tha arxisoume apo to proto
            $this->db->select()->from('unityusers')->limit($num,$start);
            $query=$this->db->get();
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: paste code not pictures

Comment: ok i will edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have accepted the answer I like to point out some basic functionality for you to more improved code.

Different technique to load the data to view from controller:

```
function index(){
    $users = $this->User->get_users();
    $this->load->view('Post_index',['users' => $users, 'any_other_data' => $any_other_data ... and so on]);
}
```

When you get post data in the controller then you should check for a validation first inside your `login` function. And in login functionality it will be more useful. [setting-validation-rules](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#setting-validation-rules)

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required',
```

Loading a model and it's function. You don't need to use uppercase in this as give below.

```
$this->load->model('user');
$this->user->get_users();
```

Your registration Function `registerSam` you don't need to create an array of post data Codeigniter will provide the functionality to get all your post data at once. To remove unnecessary data from that array use `unset`.

```
$your_post_array = $this->input->post();
```

Comment: thank you so much for all of this :) i'm learning now all these stuff and it's good to learn something more :D

Comment: just a suggestion CodeIgniter has the best user guide so you should definitely look into that. [user_guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/) @Alex1McGrady

Answer (score 0):

To call a specific function made, you can access it via a browser using the link

```
BASE_URL/index.php/ControllerName/MethodName
```

So, in your case to call the guser method, the url would be

```
BASE_URL/index.php/users/guser
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer!Now my index function has this line:
redirect(base_url().'index.php/Users/guser');

but i'm getting the error that i don't have any id given
Message: Missing argument 1 for Users::guser()

i also changed my login view form to this:

<form action="<?=base_url()?>index.php/Users/login" method="post">
<p>Username: <input name="user" type="text" /> </p>
<p>Password: <input name="password" type="password" /> </p>
<input type='hidden' id='id' name='id' value=" . $id . ">
<p><input type="submit" value="Login" /></p>

Comment: im not quite sure what you're trying to do here

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in `guser` function on the controller. You don't need to passs any argument to the function. You can get ID of user from the session, which was actually added in session once the user has entered correct credentials.

Also after login, you need to redirect user to `guser` function instead of `users`. Because as per your controller `users` function dosen't exist.

Change From

```
redirect(base_url().'index.php/Users');
```

To

```
redirect(base_url().'index.php/guser');
```

Please check below for solution.

```
function guser(){
    $data['user']=$this->User->get_user($this->session->userdata('id'));
    $this->load->view('Post_index',$data);
}
```

Let me know if it not works.